Angular PWA badging API. Update App Badge Count
I have created a PWA for android/IOS and connected it with a service for Push Notifications.
I am using PWA badging API to display badge count.
fb-sw.js,
self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.action === "badgeCount") {
    const count = event.data.count;
     if ("setAppBadge" in navigator) {
      navigator.setAppBadge(count);
    } else {
      console.log("Service Worker not supported");
    }
  }
}

messaging.ts file
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready
          .then((registration) => {
            const messageHandler = (event: MessageEvent) => {
              // console.log(" ::::  APP Badge Icon ::::::", event.data);
            };

            navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener("message", messageHandler);

            registration.active.postMessage({
              action: "badgeCount",
              count: unreadCount,
            });
            resolve(unreadCount);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error setting up message listener:", error);
            reject(error);
          });
      } else {
        reject(new Error("Service Worker not supported"));
      }
    });

However, it only updates the count when the app is open.
I want the app's badge count to update automatically whenever a push notification is received, even if the app is in the background or killed.
